# Solution of the operator equation $AX + X^*A=0$

Tags: solution-verification, linear-transformations, operator-theory, systems-of-equations

I'm searching for the solution of the following equation

$$
A X + X^* A =0
$$
where $A$ is hermitian and invertible bounded operator, while $X$ is bounded as well. I was using the following results (more general) from [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042706000677) title "Explicit solution of the operator equation $A^*X + XA^*=B$" with $B=0$.

The solution can be written as

$$
X = (I-AA^+)Y + AA^+ZA
$$

with $Y$ arbitrary and $Z$ that satisfy $A(Z+Z^*)A=0$. Here, $A^+$ is the Moore-Penrose inverse (also known as pseudo-inverse).

Since my operator $A$ is invertible, it means that the solution is

$$
X = Z A
$$

> My question is: is it possible to prove that this solution with the condition on $Z$ (i.e. $A(Z+Z^*)A=0$ is possible if and only if $Z=0$, i.e. that the only solution to the equation is the null operator $X=0$?

Comment: Pick $Z=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\-1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @KBS I don't understand, this is a 2x2 matrix, while I'm speaking about operator. Moreover, if I pick this Z and an arbitrary 2x2 A matrix I don't see how this Z realize a solution

Comment: A matrix is an operator so you can already show that this is not true in the case of matrices. Pick any symmetric $A$ and this $Z$, and you will find a solution $X$ to your equation. This will work for all $A$ since $Z+Z^T=0$. In fact, $Z$ can be any skew-symmetric matrix, and that will work with all $A$'s.